# Inner join with only one of two conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**1 - categories**

```
+--------+----------+
| id     | main_lang| 
+--------+----------+
|    1   |     ar   | 
|    2   |     en   | 
|    3   |     en   | 
+--------+----------+
```

**2 - categories_data**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+--------
| data_id|     lang  |  cat_id |  title
+--------+----------+-------------------
|    1   |     ar   |   1      | عنوان 1
|    2   |     en   |   1      | title 1
|    3   |     en   |   2      | title 2
|    4   |     en   |   3      | title 3
+--------+----------+-------------------
```

now , I want to list all categories , joined on `categories_data`.lang = ar , if that join return null, then join on `categories_data`.`lang`=`categories`.`main_lang`.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you might want to use a stored procedure and temporary tables to develop the results your are trying to achieve.  While an inline CASE or ISNULL may work, it would very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can outer join categories_data twice using different criteria:

```
SELECT c.*, cd.*, cd2.data_id AS data_id2, cd2.lang AS lang2, cd2.title AS title2
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN categories_data cd ON cd.cat_id = c.id AND cd.lang = 'ar'
LEFT JOIN categories_data cd2 ON cd.cat_id = c.id AND cd2.lang = c.main_lang AND cd2.lang != 'ar';
```

When you process the rows, you need to first test if `data_id` exists (which means there is a data row in Arabic). If `data_id` is null, you use `data_id2`, `lang2` and `title2`, which will be non-Arabic (unless they're also null, in which case you may or may not want to add a `WHERE` clause to omit such rows).